# Having trouble positioning div boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to play around with HTML/CSS and I'm having some difficulty with positioning. What I'm trying to do is have 12 boxes total (3 rows with 4 boxes in each row). The top row will be different shades of red, the second row will be different shades of green, and the bottom row will be different shades of blue. This is what the code I've come up with:

The html/css:

```css
.square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#red > .square {
  float: left;
  background: #f00;
}
#green > .square {
  float: left;
  background: #0f0;
}
#blue > .square {
  float: left;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Color Squares</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="red">
      <div class="square sq1"></div>
      <div class="square sq2"></div>
      <div class="square sq3"></div>
      <div class="square sq4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="green">
      <div class="square sq1"></div>
      <div class="square sq2"></div>
      <div class="square sq3"></div>
      <div class="square sq4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blue">
      <div class="square sq1"></div>
      <div class="square sq2"></div>
      <div class="square sq3"></div>
      <div class="square sq4"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm going to be changing the colors later, right now I'm more focused on fixing the positioning. I'm having trouble keeping the same colored boxes on the same line. I want the first row to be all red boxes, but some green boxes are coming up to the top row and some blue boxes are coming into the second row. Basically, I need a way to add a break at the end of each row to ensure that each row is made up of one color. After that I need help centering the entire thing vertically and horizontally. I know vertical centering can be kind of annoying with CSS, but I can't even get the horizontal centering right (using `margin: auto` doesn't seem to be working). Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following css, does this solve your problem?

```
.sq1 {
  clear: left;  
}
```

It tells the 1st square in each row to break with the previous float flow and start a new line.

UPDATE:

To center it, you can do the following:

```
main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -378px; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -504px; 
}
```

`margin-top` is (squareHeight + top-border-width + bottom-border-width) * 3 squares / 2.  `margin-left` is similar.  The following article explains it really well, I think: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: Thank you that fixed the rows! Now I just need to figure out how to vertically and horizontally center the entire thing.

Comment: Since you know size of everything explicitly, you might try the first option on this article: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: On .square, does display: inline-block; width: 25% help;?

Comment: my bad, yeah. Sorry, my answer was for squares of 50px.

Comment: @xdhmoore thanks for taking the time! I actually found the same article haha, but my numbers were off. Thanks for explaining all the numbers, it makes sense now :)

Edit: So just to make sure I understand this correctly, margin-left is simple (squareHeight + left-border + right-border) * 4 / 2 ?

Comment: Yep, except it'd be squareWidth (doesn't really matter since they're the same).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Anyways, thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it :)

Comment: And, it's actually easier to do what he mentions in the article the `transform` css property, but it won't work in IE8.